# How to add classes to wp custom nav <li> and <a> elements

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, nav

I have custom nav, i did put custom classes on nav ul element, but i cant put on li and a elements. There is my code

functions.php:

```
    function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('primary_navigation',__( 'Main Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

function add_menu_list_item_class($classes, $item, $args) {
  if (property_exists($args, 'list_item_class')) {
      $classes[] = $args->list_item_class;
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_menu_list_item_class', 1, 3);
```

header.php:

```
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 
                        'theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 
                        'container' => 'ul',
                        'menu_class'    => 'navbar-nav mr-auto py-4 py-md-0',
                        'list_item_class' => 'nav-item',
                        'link_class' => 'nav-link'
                    )); 
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in functions.php file of your theme to add custom class to `li` and `a` elements

**to add class to li:-**

```
  function add_menu_classes_li($classes, $item, $args) {
        if($args->menu == 'Menu Name'){
    
            if($item->post_title == 'Schedule a Demo'){
                $classes[] = 'class-name';
            }
        }
        return $classes;
    }
    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_menu_classes_li', 1, 3);
```

**To add class to a:-**

```
function add_class_to_menu_anchors( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( 0 !== $depth ) {
        $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-item';
    }
    else{
        $atts['class'] = 'custom-class';
    }

    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_to_menu_anchors', 10, 4 );
```